# Vector arrow notation in Mathematica

Tags: core-language, latex, text-formatting

I want a fast way to type vectors in Text boxes like this: $\vec a$

I can do this manually with ctrl+7+"-> "
which creates this

```
"\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(a\), \(\[Rule]\)]\)"
```

however I want it so that it converts to \vec when using TeXForm.

Is there a way to do this?

*Update*: I discovered a way to add something similar
Evaluating this:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[],{InputAliases,"vec"}]=OverscriptBox["\[SelectionPlaceholder]", "\<\[Rule]\>"]
```

and typing ESC vec ESC

However I'd still like to export this as \vec TeX

*Update 2*: I re-discovered the Built-in [OverVector](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OverVector.html) function, it doesn't look pretty on standard mode, but on TraditionalMode it works okay, however it still doesn't convert nicely to TeX